# [Python2.7]Socket Connection problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am making a socket Chat server in python 2.7 but I am unable to connect to the server using my client I get this error:

File "ChatClientV2.py", line 46, in 
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
select.error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')

I do not know why i am getting this error I need to help with this this is my code I use for the client and some extra stuff after but I do not want to be restricted by the code amount so I did not post all of it

```
import socket, select

#Function to broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    #Do not send the message to master socket and the client who has send us the   message
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection may be, chat client pressed ctrl+c for example
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)

if __name__ == "__main__":

# List to keep track of socket descriptors
CONNECTION_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 # Advisable to keep it as an exponent of 2
PORT = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# this has no effect, why ?
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(("192.168.0.8", PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

# Add server socket to the list of readable connections
CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)

print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

while 1:
    #print CONNECTION_LIST
    # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
    read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])
     for sock in read_sockets:
         #New connection
         if sock == server_socket:
             # Handle the case in which there is a new connection recieved through server_socket
             sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
             CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
             #print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

             broadcast_data(sockfd, "entered room\n")

        #Some incoming message from a client
        else:
            # Data recieved from client, process it
            try:
                #In Windows, sometimes when a TCP program closes abruptly,
                # a "Connection reset by peer" exception will be thrown
                data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                if data:
                    #broadcast_data(sock, "\r" + '<' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '> ' + data)
                    broadcast_data(sock, "\r" + data)

            except:
                broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                print "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr
                sock.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                continue

server_socket.close()
```

Comment: hey, I'm not sure you're using sockets api in an appropriate way, please post your entire code and I'll be able to inspect it and hopefully fix your problem

Comment: The posted code needs indentations fixed... and the error refers to `socket_list` not `CONNECTION_LIST` so the error code and the posted code are different. A way to debug is to print the list before the call to see what is in there.

Comment: There is literatlly nothing called socket_list in my code

Comment: @DrPrItay I edited it

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using? I've tried running it and I am not getting that error as yours, yet I am encountering a lot of other problems...

Comment: This is the code I am running on Win10 the error I get I can gyazo it if you'd like @DrPrItay

Comment: Sorry for the time it has taken me to answer, I'll run this code on some windows I'm currently on my Linux, but generally this should work on either.... anyways Ive found many problems in you're code that ARE NOT relevant to the original question you have made, I can easily fix them and post the new code here with answers to all of the commentated questions you have made

Comment: @DrPrItay Yeah that would be great thanks